# Как в Netbeans добавить новую категорию в цветовую схему?

Tags: php, netbeans

Работаю с PHP кодом. Подскажите пожалуйста как в Netbeans добавить новую категорию в цветовую схему? Хочу чтобы константы у меня были другим цветом и названия функций тоже. В шаблоне цветовой схемы в Netbeans все эти значения в одной категории "Идентификатор", как-то хочется разнообразить цветовую палитру кода.